# Call to undefined method Database_MySQLi_Result::delete()

Tags: php, kohana, sql-delete

I'm using Kohana and I'm trying to delete some data in my database. So, I made a request like this :

```
    $env_sol = ORM::factory('EnvironnementSol')
        ->where('sol_id','=',$id)
        ->and_where('environnement_id','=', $id_environnement->id)
        ->find_all();

    $env_sol->delete();
```

And I run the page, it tells me :

> Call to undefined method Database_MySQLi_Result::delete()

Can someone tell me why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ORM class you can use DB class for that purpose.

```
DB::delete('EnvironnementSol')
    ->where('sol_id','=',$id)
    ->and_where('environnement_id','=', $id_environnement->id)
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The object pointed to by `$env_sol` is of type `Database_MySQLi_Result` which does not have a `delete()` method.

Comment: Which type does it have to be ? And how can I change it please ?

Comment: @Erlaunis As far as I can tell, it is of correct type. Next time you ask a question, please be more specific about what you are trying to do. Your questions in this comment are completely off-topic for the original question you asked.

Comment: So what ? I don't think it's off-topic when I'm trying to resolve my problem, and this questions are about to do it. But nevermind, it's resolved ...

Comment: @Erlaunis You didn't ask why you couldn't delete elements in some table. Your question was about why this error occurred.